# JQuery Basic Related to jQuery.ready() or DOM ready

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen people do this way

```
$(window).load(function(){
});
```

also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

but some jquery still works outside these two functions, why?

**Update**

hmm. that means i can use $(window).load inside $(document).ready? or they should be seperated?

Comment: The first one fires when the window object has fully loaded, ie. all images etc. The second one fires when the DOM is ready, ie. when all the elements are available for manipulation. Some functions will still work outside those two if the elements are available, or if the DOM is'nt needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are only stands for

```
$(document).ready()
```

.ready  function to execute after the DOM is ready.

```
$(window).load();
```

Will execute after the page along with all its contents are done loading. This means that all images, css.

If you are writing some JS code that does not depend on selecting DOM nodes or does not need the document to be fully loaded, you can and usually should put that code outside this block.

Comment: The OP is asking for $(window).load, not $(document) :- ]